# Select Based on Existence of "class" declaration

Tags: css, class, css-selectors

Is there a way in CSS to select based on the existence of a `class` declaration, but not it's actual name? I want to say something like, for all `body` with `id=declaration` and any `class`, `display: block`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation) to test for the existence of a `class` attribute:

```
body#declaration[class] {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Can this be used in conjunction with an id selector?

Comment: @JacksonH.Egan: Yes, I accounted for that in my example.

Comment: haha! Right. Very sorry. Been at this for hours and getting sloppy. My sincere apologies.